# Error to convert the binary to image

Tags: asp.net, itext

I try to import the image from mssql varbinary(max) column to iTextSharp.
But it always shows the error "NullReferenceException" on the "phrase.Add(imageChunk)"

My code is:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)

Dim q As String = "select top 1  pic_id from pic"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(q, conn)
conn.Open()
Dim sr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

While sr.Read
    Dim byt() As Byte = CType(sr.Item("pic_id"), Byte())
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(byt)
    Dim sdi As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
    Dim img As Image = Image.GetInstance(sdi, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Dim imageChunk As Chunk = New Chunk(img, 0, 0)
    phrase.Add(imageChunk)
End While
```

The data type of that column is "varbinary(max)" and the data is like this: (0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494....................)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "phrase" is not set, it's Nothing/null. Make sure to pass correct "phrase" to your method and it will quite likely fix your problem.